# With Chrome: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: php, javascript, google-chrome, syntax-error

I am getting this error **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <** from chrome but everything works fine with FireFox.
I have found many similar posts but no solution.

So I am wondering if there is a way of sending a second page to the browser after it has been build, with it's own header.
The idea came, when I saw that Firefox places, what I echo in the function below, after the html closing tag , versus Chrome places it before the closing tag.

Basically, I like to send in this order:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset= utf-8');
<html></html>

header('Content-Type: text/javascript; charset= utf-8'); 
<script></script>
```

This is my php script, I would like to uncomment the header code and send it independently from the html page.

```
public static function jsShow($html)
{
    //header('Content-Type: text/javascript; charset= utf-8');
    echo "
        <script type=\"text/javascript\">
        var e = document.getElementById('message');
        e.innerHTML = $html ;
        e.style.display = 'block';
        </script>";
}
```

This is what the page looks like in Firefox, and this works:

```
</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
var e = document.getElementById('message');
e.innerHTML = <ul style="list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
<li style="background-color: #0000FF; margin: 0;"><img src="/asset/icon/info.gif" alt="Info: " /> working</li>
<li style="background-color: #008000; margin: 0;"><img src="/asset/icon/success.gif" alt="Success: " /> Got it</li>
</ul>
 ;
e.style.display = 'block';

</script>
```

I thought that I can maybe use ob_start() & ob_end_flush(), but you can't control headers with that only content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

...

```
        e.innerHTML = " . json_encode($html) . " ;
```

Comment: I didn't think this would work, and I don't get why it does, I just tried it out of desperation, and YAHOOO

Comment: It takes advantage of the fact that all JSON values are valid JavaScript literals.

Answer (score 2):

The error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <" is an appropriate error for what you are showing in your second code block, because it is invalid JavaScript and should fail in all browsers. You are assigning `e.innerHTML` equal to an unquoted string:

```
e.innerHTML = <ul style="list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
<li style="background-color: #0000FF; margin: 0;"><img src="/asset/icon/info.gif" alt="Info: " /> working</li>
<li style="background-color: #008000; margin: 0;"><img src="/asset/icon/success.gif" alt="Success: " /> Got it</li>
</ul>
 ;
```

See the "<" right after the "="? - that is the unexpected token.

You don't seem to use any single quotes within that string, so the simplest fix is just to wrap it in single quotes. I don't know PHP, but something like this:

```
echo "
    <script type=\"text/javascript\">
    var e = document.getElementById('message');
    e.innerHTML = '" . $html . "';
    e.style.display = 'block';
    </script>";
```

Or whatever the PHP syntax is to get this result returned to the browser:

```
e.innerHTML = '<ul style="list-style ...   </ul>';
```

By the way, it doesn't make sense to set two different headers for the same response. What you are returning is one page that is html, which happens to have a script block at the bottom. The "text/javascript" content type is more for linked JS files, which do not contain html (no script tags), just JS.

Comment: Quoting was my first thought too. But when I do quote it gives me a different error and it stops working in Firefox as well. See it think I shouldn't have to quote because it all gets transferred from a php variable to the js var. Anyhow here is what I get when I do quote:

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
            var e = document.getElementById('message');
            e.innerHTML = '<ul style="list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
        test.php:46 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
            <li style="background-color: #0000FF; margin: 0;"><img src="/asset/icon/info.gif" alt="Info: " /> test</li>
            </ul>
            ' ;
            e.style.display = 'block';
            setTimeout(function () {
                    e.style.display = 'none';
                }, 5000);
            </script>

Comment: You do have to quote it, or at least ensure that quotes end up in what the browser sees (i.e., what you see via View Source). You can't transfer directly from a PHP variable to a JS variable, the PHP runs on the server and outputs text that is then part of the page source that the browser receives. Have a look at the View Source from your accepted solution...